# Open native app from browser (not mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I would like to open a native app from my webapp is this possible?
I image something some html like this or maybe some JS?:

```
<a href="my-app://open/my/app">Open My-App</a>
```

In Mobile browsers there is something called deep linking so it is possible there. But, how about PC browsers? Is this possible in IE11?

Google keeps showing me mobile approaches which I am not interested in now :(

Comment: This question is related to your application, not to html/js. AFAIK there is certain link types which is opened by installed application (tel, mailto, magnet, etc), but I guess this type should be registered in system by application, which can handle it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work applications need to have registerred themselves as handlers for a URI scheme.  A common example is an email application being registerred to handle 'mailto:' URIs.  An MSDN reference about registerring applications can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is no way for a webapp to open an arbitrary application.  This would represent a massive security hole.